# How to use jupyter notebook in win10 subsystem?

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

It is really nice that Windows10 has Ubuntu Subsystem. After I have installed `miniconda`, I used `conda` to install `ipython` and `jupyter notebook`.

```
wangsx@SC-201708020022:~$ jupyter notebook
[I 22:57:46.113 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/wangsx
[I 22:57:46.114 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 22:57:46.114 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=0f42ee2c4a254babb7f0b5ddb1ea0dc490bab6673ce7e710
[I 22:57:46.114 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 22:57:46.116 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 22:57:46.117 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=0f42ee2c4a254babb7f0b5ddb1ea0dc490bab6673ce7e710
```

The subsystem has no web browser, how can I use `jupyter notebook`. Does it exist any trick the system can use to invoke web browser of Win10? Or just let the subsystem be a remote host, and Win10 use web browser connect to it by ip?

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting the token into a browser?

Answer (score 0):

The Win10 subsystem for Linux is still Windows. The Linux processes live side by side, and importantly use the same IP stack. So, a Win32 webbrower can indeed access `localhost:8888` and find Jupyter Notebook tehre.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answer from 
https://gist.github.com/kauffmanes/5e74916617f9993bc3479f401dfec7da

To open jupyter, type $ jupyter notebook --no-browser. The no browser flag will still run Jupyter on port 8888, but it won't pop it open automatically. it's necessary since you don't have a browser (probably) in your subsystem. In the terminal, it will give you a link to paste into your browser. If it worked, you should see your notebooks!

and Hugo Ferreira’s blog. 
https://medium.com/hugo-ferreiras-blog/using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-for-data-science-9a8e68d7610c
and
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04
Note: the lastest version of Anaconda is Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.
So just run:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh
```